# Run time error '91' object variable or with block not set

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim bradouts As Workbook
Dim bradsht As Worksheet

If Right(myfile, 4) = ".xls" Then
    Set bradouts = Workbooks.Open(myfolder & myfile)
End If

Set bradsht = bradouts.ActiveSheet <-----------------------getting error in this line

eRow = bradsht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If bradsht.Cells(3, "B") <> "" Then
    bradsht.Range(Cells(3, "B"), Cells(eRow, "L")).Copy
Else
    bradsht.Range(Cells(4, "B"), Cells(eRow, "L")).Copy
End If
```

Comment: That means that `bradouts` failed to open because the file doesn't exist or couldn't be  opened. You have the opening of the file in an `if` statement, which means that if that `if` is false and is not entered, the file is never opened. What happens when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: now that made sense to me, it repeating same error and sometimes bad filename or number and sometimes path couldn't be find......could you please let me know how to fix it

Comment: The fix is not  to run the rest of the code if the file doesn't open properly. Fix your `if` statement. If the `if` fails and the file is not opened, don't allow the rest of the code to run at all.

Comment: Keep in mind there will be issues when doing it this way: `If Right(myfile, 4) = ".xls" Then` because if the file ends in `.xlsx` it will not return true. That could be why it's "not finding it" - You may also need a backslash between `myfolder` and `myfile` depending on what their actual values are.

Comment: now it's showing bad file name or number

Comment: hey @braX i tried your suggestions but with no luck....it showing same error 91 object variable or with block not set

Comment: hey @KenWhite i'm unable to figure it out how to fix if statement any suggestions?

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Comment: Always worth qualifying if a variable has been set or not before proceeding if it may not have been so you can wrap after the first `If` loop with `If Not bradouts Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `s` in this line:

```
Set bradsht = bradouts.Activeheet
```

You probably meant Active***s***heet (with an `s`):

```
Set bradsht = bradouts.Activesheet
```

Comment: actually thats spelling mistake while posting a question, I've used "Activesheet" that's not solution

Comment: You should delete this, as it does not answer the question asked. It would be an excellent comment to the original question once you have earned the comment privilege, but you can't use this space to work around not yet having that privilege.